# measurement of the number of LUTs-FF pairs and logic cells under most efficient and inefficient condition

Tags: fpga, ise, cortex-m0

Can anyone tell me how to get the number of the LUTs-ff pairs and logic cell used under most efficient and inefficient condition in my ISE Design Summary.

I can see there are data of 'Number of Slice LUTs' and 'Number of Flip-flops', so I'm just thinking if the sum of these 2 data is the amount for most inefficient condition.

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:cortex-m0]?

Comment: I simulated cortex m0 in my experiment.

Comment: What do you mean by "most inefficient condition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the "most efficient" and "most inefficient" conditions of LUT-FF pair utilisation refers to how well your design in packed in the logic cells.

Assuming each logic cell has 1 LUT and 1 FlipFlop, the "most efficient" scenario is when you use every logic cell's LUT-FF pair, such that if you have used "L" LUTs and "F" FFs, you used only "C" cells, where

**C = L = F**

i.e. no resource in any of the cells is wasted.

In the same situation, the "most inefficient" scenario is when you haven't been able to use a single LUT-FF pair, such that using "L" LUTs and "F" flipflops made you use "C" logic cells, where

**C = L + F**

.i.e. every cell's resource is wasted.

This is of course simplistic as there are other factors including route-through elements & control set restrictions, which are beyond the scope of this answer.

I believe the map report, *design_name*.mrp will have this detail under the section **Slice Logic Distribution**.

Comment: Thanks, that is correct, my teacher taught me the same thing.